# convert lambda expression to function

Tags: c#

I wish to debug lambda expression but its not possible as it sets breakpoint on whole expression.
Here is my lambda expression

```
public bool CanRevert => _objectEntity != null && !(_objectEntity != null &&
                                                        ObjectDescription == _objectEntity.DTO.Description &&
                                                        ObjectInstance == _objectEntity.DTO.ObjectInstance.ToString() &&
                                                        Name == _objectEntity.DTO.ObjectName &&
                                                        (SelectedDevice != null && SelectedDevice.Id == _objectEntity.DTO.DeviceID) &&
                                                        (_objectEntity.DTO.ObjectCategoryID.HasValue ? (SelectedObjectCategory != null && SelectedObjectCategory.Id == _objectEntity.DTO.ObjectCategoryID.Value) : SelectedObjectCategory == null) &&
                                                        (_objectEntity.DTO.ObjectTypeID.HasValue ? (SelectedObjectType != null && SelectedObjectType.Id == _objectEntity.DTO.ObjectTypeID.Value) : SelectedObjectType == null));
```

I wanted to put breakpoint inside selectedDevice but i cant. Hence i tried to write it like

```
public bool CanRevert()

    {
        if (SelectedDevice != null)
        {
            var s = SelectedDevice.Id == _objectEntity.DTO.DeviceID;
        }
        var d = _objectEntity != null && !(_objectEntity != null &&
                                           ObjectDescription == _objectEntity.DTO.Description &&
                                           ObjectInstance == _objectEntity.DTO.ObjectInstance.ToString() &&
                                           Name == _objectEntity.DTO.ObjectName &&
                                           (SelectedDevice != null && SelectedDevice.Id == _objectEntity.DTO.DeviceID) &&
                                           (_objectEntity.DTO.ObjectCategoryID.HasValue ? (SelectedObjectCategory != null && SelectedObjectCategory.Id == _objectEntity.DTO.ObjectCategoryID.Value) : SelectedObjectCategory == null) &&
                                           (_objectEntity.DTO.ObjectTypeID.HasValue ? (SelectedObjectType != null && SelectedObjectType.Id == _objectEntity.DTO.ObjectTypeID.Value) : SelectedObjectType == null));

        return d;
    }
```

Is it right way to convert it? I ask because i am starting to get somewhere in application that Binding to this method is not supported

Comment: You do not have a lambda. You have an [expression-bodied read-only property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#read-only-properties).

Comment: @GSerg how to debug it ?

Comment: Set a breakpoint on it, and when hit hover your mouse over your `SelectedDevice`?

Comment: Why not put a breakpoint inside eg the aid property of SelectedDevice?

Comment: @CaiusJard but when i put then it puts on whole property

Comment: You can breakpoint the set and get separately in a property?? Put them on different lines

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same result like this.

- Put a breakpoint in your expression.
- Start Debugging (<kbd>F5</kbd>)
- Highlight `(SelectedDevice != null && SelectedDevice.Id == _objectEntity.DTO.DeviceID)` in your expression
- Right-click and select `Add Watch`
- Now you have its calculated value in the Watch window. (Usually pops up at the bottom)
- You can use `Quick Watch` (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>) if you want its value once.